# How to create a self sizing grid in a UITableView cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to build a UITableView similar to this. There are some regular cells and I want one cell to be a grid like this. There should be exactly 20 columns, and cells should be square. So they need to have a width and height of UITableView's width / 20. Also UITableViewCell containing all this items should have the height 5 times of this. How do I make this happen?

Comment: In tableview cell did you try to use stackview ?

Comment: You suggest 5 horizontal stackviews to hold items, and 1 vertical stackview to hold stackviews?

Comment: Yes or you can put collection view

Comment: How do I set the sizes of items in collectionview?

Comment: @user3179249 Implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method `collectionView(layout: sizeForItemAt:)`. But if you know the exact number of cells, a `UIStackView` would be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the exact number of columns and rows, this is easy to achieve without any code, using a storyboard.

Using nested 5 x 4 `UIStackViews`, each inner stack view containing 20 alternately coloured `UIView`s, with all stack views **Distribution** to **Fill Equally**, and a single cell's Aspect Ratio constraint to 1:1…

[image]

Et voila…

[image]

Of course, knowing this technique you could easily create the same in code.